# How to customize or create a form in the Softpro server package?

Tags: plugins, package, sdk, form-designer, windows-application-packaging

I need to customize or create a new form in the Softpro server package. Is there any document related to this.

Reviewed the Softpro SDK document and there is points related to the server package installation. The document contains installation and details about the SDK not the information related to custom design.